# How to determine the user name after binding to LDAP via SASL?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, sasl

During user log-on, my server app (Windows/Linux) is receiving the user credentials from the Windows client app, obtained via SSPI (`InitializeSecurityContext`).  I can use `ldap_sasl_bind_s` on the server to bind to the LDAP server, but I cannot find a way to reliably determine the user name.  Is there a way of doing this via the LDAP (v3) API?

If the server ran on Windows, I would be able to use SSPI directly and determine the user id using `AcceptSecurityContext` and `QueryCredentialsAttributes`.  On Linux, I would need to use GSSAPI/Kerberos, but that requires that I take extra steps to register the server app within the Kerberos framework.

Comment: There is an LDAP `whoami` request.

Comment: Thanks, that's the pointer that I needed.  There is a function ldap_whoami_s on Linux, it does not seem to exist on Windows (in Winldap.h), which is why it escaped my attention.  If you post your comment I'll be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Note that MS AD doesn't support this request on the server side, either.

Comment: I successfully wrote my own implementation of ldap_whoami_s for Windows using Winldap, using ldap_extended_operation+ldap_result+ldap_parse_extended_result and it seems to work fine against our AD.